# I am trying to generate a pdf using iText5 with a fix header and page number in every page

Tags: java, html, jsp, itext

I am trying to generate a pdf using iText5 where a fix header and page number on footer will present on every page.Content of the page will come dynamically and number of pages will also generate dynamically depending upon the content.
I have used **HTMLWorker**. Pdf is generating fine but problem is unable to give fix header and page number in every page.
Any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

Here is my minimal code reference

```
    OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File(Mypath+docName+".pdf"));
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,file);
    HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
    document.open();

    String printContent="";

    printContent += "<table border='0' width='100%'>";
    printContent += "   <tr>";
    printContent += "       <td align='right'><u><b>My Fix Header</b></u></td>";
    printContent += "   </tr>";
    printContent += "</table>";

    //while(rs.next())
    {        
        printContent+=" <div style='width: 100%; font-size: 12px;' align='justify'>Here I will fetch some data from the database. Accordingly, page sizes will increase and new pages will be added.</div>";
    } 
 
    printContent += "<p align='center'>1/10(page number footer)</p>";
    
    htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(printContent));
    document.close(); 
    file.close();
    writer.flush();
```

Comment: Can you share what you tried through the means of a minimal reproducable example? And the output PDF? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I would recommend using iText 7's open source pdfHTML add-on for true HTML to PDF support or at the very least look into XMLWorker for iText 5, although it has its limitations. HTMLWorker is a deprecated class.

Comment: Hi @Ankuran, Share some code snippet that you tried and also the error if any.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.